# having a hard time saving c++ data to csv

Tags: c++, csv

I'm using c++ for a windows application and I will need to save some data while the application is running. Since I will most likely use Excel to work with the data later on, I was trying to save it in CSV.

I couldn't find anywhere a good way of doing so. What I want to do is to ever time I start the program, to write the name of the user (which will be asked), get a new line and start a table with simulation time and a data value. What I would need for that is a way to:

1) Identify the last line of the file when the application is started

2) a way to jump back and forth in the last 2 lines, so I can save time values and data values in a synchronized way.

Pseudo-code for what I want to do:

```
read file, take last line as n
add to file, line n+1: 1
add to file, line n+2: x
add to file, line n+1: 2
add to file, line n+2: y
(etc...)
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: Instead of creating a new file for each user, just continuously rewrite the same file.  Every time you need to edit it, read the entire file into memory, edit what you need to edit in memory, then write the entire file back out, using the same save name.

Comment: @nhgrif please refrain from using comments to answer.  Consider rewriting your comment as an answer.

Comment: Yes, creating new files would be a last resort in case I cannot manage to edit the file in the way that I want to. It would make the data analysis harder by doing so.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the file?  What parts are you editing?  Just the last two lines?  Nothing else ever gets edited?  Is there content besides the last two lines?

Comment: Pretty much every time that I run the program, I need to append the following scheme to the file:
subject number x \n
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, (...) \n
0.1, 0.7, 1.3, 0.8, 1.9, 0.5, (...) \n

Both lines are data that the program gets, the first one is sequential, the second one isn't. I need a way to append something to line 2 then line 3, then line 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use two files, or change the data format to a sequence of pairs of values.